# How to organize CSS Sheets

Tags: css

I would wish to start a discussion to get some good ideas on how to organise style sheets in a very big project with a big team of developers working on it.

One possible approach here is to have just one sheet with all the styles organized using comments and regions, unfortunately even using a one-lined writing approach with tabs this sheet would become incredibly big and even having SVN commits and updates could become messier.

So we think it would be better to divide styles in different sheets. What we are not sure is how to organize this as we have different ideas for it.

- One possible idea is to organize it for types: colors.css, fonts.css, forms.css, ...
- Another idea is to group them by functionality/behaviour: navigator.css, menu.css, warnings.css, errors.css, ...
- We could also organize them by page: login.css, contact.css, home.css, ...
- Or even use a combination of those three ideas together.

Now what worries me is the fact that we would prefer not to add all the styles to every page, as not all the pages require all the styles and we are really worried about performance as our project is consumed by millions of users everyday. We of course compress it later on deploying but even so we think it's wiser to load only the required ones per page.

On being so, I am worried about other developers not loading styles in correct order, as having different sheets needed to be loaded depending on the page, or on the group of pages, they could get this messed up and on doing so cascading will fail (imagine they load menu.css before global.css, global would override some menu styles!!!).

Now we could just go for one sheet, we could just load all of them always, or we could use some idea we came to like using an alphabetical prefix to tell developers the loading order:

- a_global.css
- a_forms.css
- b_region1.css
- b_anotherregion.css
- c_page.css

But that looks a bit horrible being honest. So now I was wondering if there is some type of popular css architecturing out there or at least some good ideas we could use for our project here.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: In any case when thinking about organising your CSS you should have a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), they're CSS preprocessors intended to make authoring CSS more dynamic, organized and productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go with a preprocessor, so you can organize source files however you want. (Our team uses LESS, because we've started with Twitter Bootsrap and it stuck). The compiled CSS file should not be under version control, each developer should compile their own version for testing. I'd recommend a grunt task to compile a minified version for production. I'd go with component-centric approach (forms, navs, grid, typography etc).
2. Using a preprocessor gives you the power of variables and mixins. You can keep files like variables.less and mixins.less in which you define common styles. So you when that blue color changes into slightly lighter blue you just change it in one file.
3. One large file including all the CSS you need should be fine as it is cached by browsers, so it minimizes HTTP requests to your serwver. Page-specific stylesheets are OK when a particular page has many uncommon elements.
4. Create a style guide html template which includes every common element you can think of. Headings, link colors, lists, photo thumbnails, form inputs, grid configurations, accordions etc. When you need to create a new component add it to this template, modify the stylesheets, see if it breaks any other  elements and how it fits with the rest. Then use these snippets to create particular pages.

Answer (score 1):

**SASS or LESS**

This will help you to keep your code easy managed. (variables, mixins etc)

**Divide in multiple count of files.**

Always a good idea. How to divide. 
I suggest basically to divide them per page.

**BUT** - 
Exclude general styles to seperate files which will be included everywhere.

By the way, one single file doesn't imply low performance. Are you sure that 10 requests for smaller sheets will be faster than one request for bigger file?
Additionally this files will be cached in web browser, so one file doesn't look like a bad idea.

Comment: Thx, I choose the other as correct even though both are very similar just because it seems more complete to me. +1 though